# Trying to mount backup of /dev/sda as ext4 for recovery, fdisk reports invalid partition table

Tags: partitioning, mount, filesystem, ext4

I used `dd if=/dev/sda of=~/backup.img` where `/dev/sda` was an ext4 filesystem. I want to perform recovery on it which means I need to mount it as ext4 filesystem using [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/) application. Can anyone help me mount this properly?

Output from `dumpe2fs -h`:

```
dumpe2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)  
Filesystem volume name:   DOROOT  
Last mounted on:          /  
Filesystem UUID:          6c4f1456-a5bb-4d1d-afd4-a13d0a1ce63d  
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53  
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)  
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize  
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash  
Default mount options:    (none)  
Filesystem state:         clean  
Errors behavior:          Continue  
Filesystem OS type:       Linux  
Inode count:              1310720  
Block count:              5242880  
Reserved block count:     262144  
Free blocks:              4116242  
Free inodes:              1127629  
First block:              0  
Block size:               4096  
Fragment size:            4096  
Reserved GDT blocks:      1022  
Blocks per group:         32768  
Fragments per group:      32768  
Inodes per group:         8192  
Inode blocks per group:   512  
Flex block group size:    16  
Filesystem created:       Thu May  3 16:58:15 2012  
Last mount time:          Sat Jul 13 10:24:27 2013  
Last write time:          Thu Mar 28 12:54:31 2013  
Mount count:              2  
Maximum mount count:      29  
Last checked:             Thu Mar 28 12:54:31 2013  
Check interval:           15552000 (6 months)  
Next check after:         Tue Sep 24 12:54:31 2013  
Lifetime writes:          724 MB  
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)  
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)  
First inode:              11  
Inode size:           256  
Required extra isize:     28  
Desired extra isize:      28  
Journal inode:            8  
Default directory hash:   half_md4  
Directory Hash Seed:      9eb0125c-e592-492e-87ad-aaf42f92061d  
Journal backup:           inode blocks  
Journal features:         journal_incompat_revoke  
Journal size:             128M  
Journal length:           32768  
Journal sequence:         0x0006800e  
Journal start:            23393
```

Output from `fdisk -lu`:

```
Disk ssdback: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes  
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2610 cylinders, total 41943040 sectors  
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Disk identifier: 0x00000000  
Disk ssdback doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Output from `df`:

`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda         20G  3.4G   16G  18% /

udev            242M  8.0K  242M   1% /dev

tmpfs            99M  208K   99M   1% /run

none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock

none            246M     0  246M   0% /run/shm`

Output from `blkid /dev/sda`:

`/dev/sda: LABEL="DOROOT" UUID="6c4f1456-a5bb-4d1d-afd4-a13d0a1ce63d" TYPE="ext4"`

Answer (score 0):

The dd command you used:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=~/backup.img
```

is for backing up the **harddrive(/dev/sda)** to your **home directory/image.img**  
isn't that forming a loop.

Did it worked ...??

and for mounting a partition:

```
 mkdir /media/mountPoint
```

mount /dev/sda5 /media/mountPoint

Your device will be mounted at **/media/mountPoint**.

Comment: It would not be a loop if there's another physical disk that holds the `/home` directory. If the system has just one physical disk, though, you're right that you'd never be able to create a complete backup using `dd` in this way.

Comment: hi user182904, yes I did issue the `dd if=/dev/sda of=~/backup.img` command

Comment: @dougvk
If you want to do recover, don't mount it. 
use this commmand
** `dd if=~/backup.img of=/dev/sda` **

**NOTE:   This command will copy all the data from ~/backup.img and copy to /dev/sda, and if there is important data on /dev/sda, you'll lose it...**
Use it properly !!
If i'm wrong somewhere, pls do tell me ..!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You say that "`/dev/sda` was an ext4 filesystem." If this statement is accurate, it means that the *entire disk* was *one* filesystem, *without* a partition table. If so, `fdisk` will be useless on the disk, because `fdisk` manipulates partition tables, and your disk has no such data structure. It's valid to create a filesystem on the whole disk in this way, but it's unusual; it's much more common to create a partition table on the disk, even if you intend to use the whole thing as one filesystem. Since you didn't report device filenames with your other commands, it's unclear whether you've actually set things up in this way or if you have some sort of problem. You might be able to figure it out by using `blkid`, as in:

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/sda
/dev/sda: UUID="a139b90e-2f94-4378-bf66-fe7669808dbe" TYPE="ext4"
```

This example shows that `/dev/sda` does indeed hole a valid ext4 filesystem. You can also look for device files for partitions in `/dev`, as in:

```
$ ls /dev/sda*
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda3  /dev/sda4  /dev/sda5
```

This example, contrary to the earlier one, shows that `/dev/sda` is partitioned -- that's what the files that end in numbers refer to.

Comment: hi, i used the command `dd if=/dev/sda of=~/sda.img` and I edited my above question to include the filesystem layout and other information you requested